# How many Radio Buttons can be checked at any one time in this specific form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, button, radio-button

If a Form contains 2 Group Boxes each containing 3 Radio Buttons and the Form
itself contains 5 Radio Buttons not in either of the Group Boxes how many Radio
Buttons can be checked at any one time?

1.. 2... 3... more?

Comment: 1 per Group Box, then the other 5 can all be selected at one time unless they are set to be in the same radio group. That would make 7? Easiest way would be just to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say 7:

- 1 out of the first group box
- 1 out of the second group box
- 5 out of the remaining not in group boxes (assuming they do not belong to the same radio button group property)